# Clojure watch function executing, but 'map' as part of function not executing

Tags: clojure

```
(defonce instance
  (atom
    {:id nil
     :canvas nil
     :subscribers #{"test1" "test2"}))

(defn replace-canvas [canvas id]
  (println "replaced" id "'s canvas"))

(defn update-subscribers
  [k r old-state new-state]
  (pprint "this function is being called")
  (pprint "I can execute consecutive forms")
  (map (partial replace-canvas (new-state :canvas))
       (new-state :subscribers)))

(add-watch instance :update-subs update-subscribers)
```

when the instance atom changes, the watch function ostensibly is called because "this function is being called" and "I can execute consecutive forms" are both printed, but the map function never seems to take place. I'm not sure why this would be, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation for add-watch that placed restrictions on what could be put inside the watch function.

Even if I replace the map in update-subscribers with something more straightforward like

```
(map println (new-state :subscribers))
```

the map doen't seem to have any effect.

Any help would be appreciated,
 thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `map` function is lazy so it only does its work if a caller realizes the sequence it produces (which is not the case when a function is invoked as part of a watch because the result is essentially thrown away).

You'll either want to wrap the `map` call in `doall`, or use `doseq` instead (which is more idiomatic for side-effecting code):

```
(doseq [subscriber (:subscribers new-state)]
  (replace-canvas (:canvas new-state) subscriber))
```

Note also that `(:canvas new-state)` is more idiomatic than `(new-state :canvas)` - keyword first.